# Script SSH and run command

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I must connect to server every day by ssh, and I made a script to display logs.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=`date +%Y`
M=`date +%m`
D=`date +%d`

gnome-terminal --geometry=82x11 \
--tab --title "NAMEServer" -e "sshpass -p P4ssw0rd ssh USER@123.456.789.10 'tail -f /opt/logs/example.$A-$M-$D.log'" \
--tab --title "NAMEServer" -e "sshpass -p P4ssw0rd ssh USER@123.456.789.10 'tail -f /opt/logs/example.$A-$M-$D.log'"
```

But if I try filter a words with grep, not working.
Example:

```
-e "sshpass -p P4ssw0rd ssh USAER@123.456.789.10 'tail -f /opt/logs/example.$A-$M-$D.log | grep 'not fetch''" \
```

or

```
-e "sshpass -p P4ssw0rd ssh USAER@123.456.789.10 'cat /opt/logs/exaple.log | grep 'any problem''" \
```

I think the problem is the quotation marks, but, which use?, I tried with `´´ ' ' " "`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is your quotation marks. You are nesting single quotes without escaping. Try this:

```
-e "sshpass -p P4ssw0rd ssh USAER@123.456.789.10 'cat /opt/logs/exaple.log | grep \'any problem\''" \
```

Comment: thanks @forquare, but I tried it, or assign a variable and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding bash at the end like:

```
e "sshpass -p P4ssw0rd ssh USAER@123.456.789.10 'tail -f /opt/logs/example.$A-$M-$D.log | grep 'not fetch'; bash' " \
```